# linker error LNK1109

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, linker-errors, tao

i tried to compile the [ACE](http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu/) 5.6.1 library with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 SP1. This project contains 609 subprojects. And everytime I try to rebuild them all, some, not the same, will not compile and exit with the following error [LNK1109](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/207183ye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
I am sure, non of the descripte resons are matching in my case. So what else could it be?

As a workaround, I just pressed "build" and as a result it looks like that it worked (the missing subprojects now will be build). So my other question is, are the result the same as a successfully rebuild in the first place? So I can ensure, that no file is corrupt? And why is it working now?

I tried already reducing the amount of parallel builds, didn't matter if I select one or four.

Comment: Check your project dependencies chances are after a clean and build you may get linker errors if common libraries aren't built before dependent projects attempt to link them. The other possibility is something is running that is using the library ...

Comment: How about some English links?

Comment: @Lirik I fixed MSDN link

Comment: 609 sub-projects?  Oh dear.  You must have missed the Ciao project.

Comment: thanks for fixing the link. The basic conditions are given, so i can't change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen similar issues in the past caused by virus checkers holding open files. Although I've not seen that recently it might be worth checking?